# equation of y=f(x) after it has been reflected in the line x=k

Tags: coordinate-systems

What is the equation of y=f(x) after it has been reflected in the line x=k

For example if k=0 then it would be the y axis so the new equation would be y=f(-x)

In addition what is the equation of y=f(x) after it has been reflected in the line y=K

generally how do you find the equation of y=f(x) after reflection in line y=mx+c

Answer (score 1):

HINT: You need a transformation $x\mapsto ax+b$ for constants $a$ and $b$ such that $k+\epsilon\mapsto k-\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon\in\Bbb R$.

This should allow you to find $a$ and $b$ immediately.

Same story (with the due modifications) for the reflection around $y=k$.